# Elegant way to init function on set

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have function foo take jquery wrapped node as an argument. Is there more elegant way to run this function on nodes set?

The way I do it:

```
$('.for-foo').each(function () {
    foo($(this));
});
```

Comment: what is the purpose of function `foo()`? bcoz, answer depend on it, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it a plugin:

```
$.fn.foo = function(){
  return this.each(function(){
    // do something to each element "this"
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
$('.for-foo').foo();
```

This will also make it chainable with other jQuery functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in the selection to the function, like this:

```
foo($(".for-foo"));
```

Your `foo` function would then look like this:

```
function foo(selection) {
    selection.each(function() {
        // do stuff with each current node
    });
}
```

`foo` is messier, but at least it's a lot cleaner to call.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of you `foo()` is not clear and answer may varies on that. One typical example can be:

```
function foo($el) {
    $el.css('color', function(i) {
        return ['black', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red'][i];
    });
}
foo( $('.for-foo') );
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/607/)**